# How can I get ImageJ to open all files in the same session?

Tags: nautilus, image-processing

When I open more than one image from Nautilus in ImageJ they all open in a new session. If I already have one session running and open a new file in Nautilus ImageJ also creates a new session. How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution works only for multiple files at once and not for new images. But to do this, I believe, you have to change the source code of ImageJ.

---

1. Create an  additionally private desktop file `imagej.desktop`.

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/imagej.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.local/share/applications/imagej.desktop
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/imagej.desktop
   ```
2. Find the `Exec` line:

   ```
   Exec=imagej %f
   ```

   and replace the line with

   ```
   Exec=imagej %F
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Restart nautilus

   ```
   nautilus -q
   ```

---

```
Add...  Accepts...
%f      a single filename.
%F      multiple filenames.
%u      a single URL.
%U      multiple URLs.
%d      a single directory. Used in conjunction with %f to locate a file.
%D      multiple directories. Used in conjunction with %F to locate files.
%n      a single filename without a path.
%N      multiple filenames without paths.
%k      a URI or local filename of the location of the desktop file.
%v      the name of the Device entry.
```

Comment: This works fine if I open multiple files from nautilus but still does not open new images in the existing session.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This works only for multiple files at once and not for new images. But to do this, I believe, you have to change the source code.